# Proper way to return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I want to delete a member from `Members` table if and only of the member has no transaction in `MEMBERS_TRANSACTION` table.

I also want to know whether the member has any transaction. Currently I will return a column with the value of `1` to indicate at least one transaction exists for that member, or `0` to indicate that the member has no transaction and has been deleted upon the execution of this query. My query is as follows:

```
IF EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT members_trans_id 
    FROM MEMBERS_TRANSACTION 
    WHERE member_link_id = 188
) 
    SELECT 1 
ELSE 
    DELETE FROM Members WHERE member_link_id = 188;
    SELECT 0
```

My concern is the two lines in `ELSE` block. I can execute this query with no problem at SQL Server Management Studio, but I wonder if it is *correct* to write it that way.

I'm using SQL server 2008 R2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Left Joins are your friend and very fast. To view all members and their transactions:

```
select m.Name, count(*) As TotalTransactions
from Member m
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS_TRANSACTION mt on mt.member_link_id=m.member_link_id
where mt.member_link_id is null
GROUP BY m.Name
ORDER BY m.Name
```

(to find only the ones with no transactions, add a HAVING COUNT(*)=0 to the end)

To zap the freeloaders:

```
delete m
from Member m
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS_TRANSACTION mt on mt.member_link_id=m.member_link_id
where mt.member_link_id is null
```

I'm assuming you want to do this for all members. Obviously for a single one add their ID in the where clauses.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in just one query, i.e one database call. As for the second query you gave me, it will delete the selected member (by `member_link_id`) even when the member has transaction in `MEMBERS_TRANSACTION` table

Answer (score 0):

Eigher you join or give sub-query, from both you will achieve this.  Good to use join.

In sqlserver 2008, [Merge statement](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/) introduce which is very good in this condition.

Also read the good article about basic when we use what:-

[left outer v/s not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777910/sql-performance-on-left-outer-join-vs-not-exists) and [not in v/s not exist](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Always use select query before delete this query

```
create table Members (member_link_id int , name varchar(50))
create table MEMBERS_TRANSACTION ( members_trans_id int , member_link_id int, name varchar(50))

insert into Members values(188,'abc'),(189,'abc1'),(190,'abc2'),(192,'abc3'),(193,'abc4')
insert into MEMBERS_TRANSACTION values(1,189,'abc'),(2,190,'abc1')

/*for select with left outer join to understand better*/
select * from Members m left outer join MEMBERS_TRANSACTION mt on m.member_link_id = mt.member_link_id

-/*1st approach*/
select * from Members m 
where not exists ( select members_trans_id from MEMBERS_TRANSACTION mt where m.member_link_id = mt.member_link_id )
and member_link_id = 188

select * from Members m 
where not exists ( select members_trans_id from MEMBERS_TRANSACTION mt where m.member_link_id = mt.member_link_id )
and member_link_id = 189

/*2nd approach with merge option, it is give error*/
MERGE Members AS m
USING (SELECT member_link_id FROM MEMBERS_TRANSACTION ) AS mt
ON mt.member_link_id = m.member_link_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
SELECT * from Members 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
SELECT * from Members where m.member_link_id = 188

drop table member
drop table MEMBERS_TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I'm sorry but there's syntax error in the second query. On the other hand, the first query deletes all members whose `member_link_id` is not 188. This is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to delete member whose `member_link_id` is 188 if and only if this member has no transaction. I also want to know whether the outcome of this query execution, whether the member has been deleted, or he has not been deleted due to existing transaction

Comment: dear give me 10 min to modify this

Answer (score 0):

Just attempt the delete and examine the modified row count returned by SQL Server:

```
DELETE FROM Members
WHERE member_link_id = 188 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM MEMBERS_TRANSACTION 
    WHERE member_link_id = 188
)
```

I recommend to have as little procedural logic in T-SQL. C# is much better equipped to handle logic.