# Checking for two fields in a record

Tags: sql

I am trying to eliminate only records where both fields match the given values from another table.

```
SELECT CODE, NUM 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE  (CODE not in (SELECT CODE FROM TABLE_B) AND NUM not in (SELECT NUM FROM TABLE_B))
```

However this seems to eliminate ALL records that have either of these values.  I need to eliminate only the records that have both matching a given record from TABLE2.   An OR seems counter-intuitive here?

Comment: It's not working because your subqueries boil down to `code NOT IN (all code values from B) AND num NOT IN (all num values from B)`. There's no knowledge of WHICH records those code/num values came from, so you're not checking if the SAME record contains both values. just **ANY** records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CODE, NUM 
FROM TABLE_A TA
WHERE  
not exists (select 1 from TABLE_B TB where TB.CODE=TA.CODE)
and 
not exists (select 1 from TABLE_B TB where TB.NUM=TA.NUM)
```

Comment: This does the same thing the OP is already doing, with better performance: but the question isn't how to speed it up, the question is how to change it to consider both values at the same time.

Comment: Yes.  Same result unfortunately.

Comment: @user1327418 If that is not what you need then Multisync's answer should do what you asked for. Otherwise please provide sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CODE, NUM 
FROM TABLE_A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_B b where b.CODE = a.CODE and b.NUM = a.NUM);
```

> The EXISTS keyword tests for the existence of any rows in a subquery.
>   If no rows are found, the answer is FALSE. Otherwise, the subquery
>   returns TRUE. NOT EXISTS reverses the results.

Comment: My subquery will indeed be returning a lot of rows.  I need to compare row to row.

Comment: @user1327418 It's a correlated subquery which is executed for each row of TABLE_A. And it's generally faster then NOT IN. Are you sure that the query "SELECT * FROM TABLE_B b where b.CODE = x and b.NUM = y" returns a lot of rows?

Comment: @user1327418 Anyway in your case you have to full scan both tables so using NOT EXISTs is appropriate here. As I know Oracle stops searching if it finds something with NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @user1327418 I gave you Oracle behaviour of EXISTS. You may also check this question if you're interested in performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777910/sql-performance-on-left-outer-join-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the performance of NOT EXISTS, you could also try to check the same condition with a LEFT OUTER JOIN and a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
    a.CODE, 
    a.NUM 
FROM 
    TABLE_A a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN -- return all from table A, and matches from table B
    TABLE_B b ON 
        a.CODE = b.CODE AND 
        a.NUM = b.NUM 
WHERE b.CODE IS NULL -- filter out the ones that matched; think of this as a reverse INNER
```