# SQL return records that have some associations and exclude others

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "AssetGroups" ag
  INNER JOIN "AssetGroupsTags" agt ON ag."Id" = agt."AssetGroupId"
  WHERE  agt."TagId" IN (63, 77) AND agt."TagId" NOT IN (97);
```

This returns record with the ID of 1031. When I run this query:

```
SELECT "TagId" FROM "AssetGroupsTags" WHERE "AssetGroupId" = 1031;
```

It returns 97, 63, 27. I would think that the `AND` and the `NOT IN` would preclude record 1031, but it is not happening.

To be clear: I want to return any records that have `TagId` of 63 or 77, but also do not have a tag of 97.

Comment: `TagId` is a comma separated list values in a string? If so, you can't use `IN`.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Nick it's not a string, it's a list of values returned.

Comment: @eltiare, can you paste some data samples here, from the current scenario if I'm getting correctly you can use self join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using `not exists`:

```
select *
from assetgroups ag
    join assetgroupstags agt on ag.id = agt.assetgroupid
where agt.tagid in (63, 77) 
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from assetgroupstags agt2 
        where agt.assetgroupid = agt2.assetgroupid and agt2.tagid = 97
    )
```

This will return any `assetgroups` that have a `tagid` of 63 or 77, but not those with 97.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the cleanest way to go.

Comment: Glad it helped.  There are other options like using an `outer join` with a `null` check, but I think this is the most explicit.

Comment: @sgeddes, which one is good performance wise, either `self join` or using `not exists`?

Comment: @GauravGenius -- I believe it depends a bit on the database, but in general, `exists` will short-circuit on the first match, where `outer joins` will iterate over all matches.  With that said, the `outer join` in this case would only ever have a single record so I'd imagine they'd produce nearly identical execution plans.  Here's a potentially relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777910/sql-performance-on-left-outer-join-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 0):

I would just use aggregation:

```
SELECT agt."AssetGroupId"
FROM "AssetGroupsTags" agt 
GROUP BY agt."AssetGroupId"
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN agt."TagId" IN (63, 77) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN agt."TagId" IN (97) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

If you want other fields in addition to the group id, then you can join them in.