# Trying to optimize a system objects search

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m trying to search the database for any stored procedures that contain one of about 3500 different values.

I created a table to store the values in. I’m running the query below. The problem is, just testing it with a SELECT TOP 100 is taking 3+ mins to run (I have 3500+ values). I know it’s happening due to the query using LIKE.

I’m wondering if anyone has an idea on how I could optimize the search. The only results I need are the names of every value being searched for (pulled directly from the table I created: “SearchTerms”) and then a column that displays a 1 if it exists, 0 if it doesn’t.

Here’s the query I’m running:

```
SELECT
trm.Pattern,
(CASE 
WHEN sm.object_id IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE 1
END) AS “Exists”

FROM dbo.SearchTerms trm
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules sm
ON sm.definition LIKE '%' + trm.Pattern + '%'

ORDER BY trm.Pattern
```

Note: it’s a one-time deal —it’s not something that will be run consistently.

Comment: The optimal way would be to create a CLR table valued function that accepts a string and uses regex to search it and return a result for each of the 3,500 terms matched. Then you only need 1 scan of `sys.sql_modules` and `cross apply` of your function - with each definition being processed once (rather than 3,500+ full scans)

Answer (score 0):

Try `CTE` and get your Patterns which exists in any stored procedure with `WHERE` condition using `EXISTS (...)`. Then use `LEFT JOIN` with `dbo.SearchTerms` and your `CTE` to get `1` or `0` value for `Exists` column.

```
;WITH ExistsSearchTerms AS (
    SELECT Pattern
    FROM dbo.SearchTerms
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.sql_modules sm WHERE sm.definition LIKE '%' + Pattern + '%')
)
SELECT trm.Pattern, IIF(trmExist.Pattern IS NULL, 0, 1) AS "Exists"
FROM dbo.SearchTerms trm
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SearchTerms trmExist
        ON trm.Pattern = trmExist.Pattern
ORDER BY Pattern
```

Reference :

- [SQL performance on LEFT OUTER JOIN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778034/9695286)
- [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: This was much more efficient. Quick question: how can I tweak the query to display the object name?

Comment: Query is efficient because when it will short circuit after encountering `first sp` that contains given `Pattern` and `won't check for remaining sp`. If you need only one of the name of `object id` that contains `Pattern` then it can still be efficient but if you want all `Object ids` then your query is the solution.