Select unrelated in a n:m relationship
I have a typical many-to-many relationship resolved by a join table, as shown here:

For this question the sample data is:
People:



PersonID
Name




P001
Alice


P002
Bob


P003
Carlos


P004
David



Courses:



CourseID
Course




C001
Algebra


C002
Biology


C003
Chemistry



Attendance:



CourseID
PersonID




C001
P001


C001
P002


C001
P003


C002
P002


C002
P003


C003
P003



The following query:
SELECT Courses.CourseID, Courses.Course, People.PersonID, People.Name
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN Attendance ON Courses.CourseID = Attendance.CourseID
INNER JOIN People ON Attendance.PersonID = People.PersonID

gives me a flat list of attendances by course:
C001,Algebra,P001,Alice
C001,Algebra,P002,Bob
C001,Algebra,P003,Carlos
C002,Biology,P002,Bob
C002,Biology,P003,Carlos
C003,Chemistry,P003,Carlos

Now I am trying to get a similar, but opposite result - i.e. a list of people who did NOT attend each course, which should look like this:
Expected result:
C001,Algebra,P004,David
C002,Biology,P001,Alice
C002,Biology,P004,David
C003,Chemistry,P001,Alice
C003,Chemistry,P001,Bob
C003,Chemistry,P004,David

I was hoping I could use something like:
SELECT Courses.CourseID, Courses.Course, People.PersonID, People.Name
FROM Courses
CROSS JOIN People
WHERE People.PersonID IN (
SELECT Attendance.PersonID
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN Attendance ON Attendance.CourseID = Courses.CourseID
)

but unfortunately that returns:
C001,Algebra,P001,Alice
C001,Algebra,P002,Bob
C001,Algebra,P003,Carlos
C002,Biology,P001,Alice
C002,Biology,P002,Bob
C002,Biology,P003,Carlos
C003,Chemistry,P001,Alice
C003,Chemistry,P002,Bob
C003,Chemistry,P003,Carlos

which suggests that the subquery is performed once for all courses, not individually for each course.
IMPORTANT:
The application I am using (Claris FileMaker) implements a very limited subset of the SQL-92 standard (and isn't very well documented to boot). I can only use the SELECT statement with a handful of clauses, and AFAICT only INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN and CROSS JOIN are allowed. Also I haven't been able to implement a subquery anywhere except inside a WHERE clause.
Is it at all possible to return the expected result using only plain, basic SQL?

something like this should work
select *
from Courses as c cross join People as p
left outer join Attendance as a
on (c.CourseID = a.CourseID and p.PersonID = a.PersonID)
where a.AttendId is null

the main trick is to generate Cartesian product of all courses/people first - ie all combinations
then, we use left join to find matching attendance records, but because it is LEFT join - it will not exclude non matching records, all non matching combinations will have null as value from attendance table

This is interesting. Can you add a few words to explain HOW this works? Of course, a.AttendId is NEVER null, so it is very puzzling to me.

@y.arazim left join will produce null for missing attendance records

With the correct indexes, NOT EXISTS will perform better than LEFT JOIN. You should give it a try.

@IłyaBursov Thank you. I think I am beginning to wrap my head around this. So I was on the right track by starting with a Cartesian product, but I didn't know you could select widows by specifying IS NULL on a field of a (non-existing) child.

@antonio_mg Would this be a correct implementation of your suggestion: SELECT Courses.Course, People.Name FROM Courses CROSS JOIN People  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Attendance.AttendID FROM Attendance  WHERE Courses.CourseID = Attendance.CourseID and People.PersonID = Attendance.PersonID)?    If not, please post an answer of your own.

You got it! The main difference between NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN is that LEFT JOIN first joins records then filter, this can be very bad if you have a lot of records for each Person in Attendance table. Check this answer where its better explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778034/3243074

@antonio_mg Interesting read. Thanks again.
